What probability distribution is learned in this specific case?
I keep reading papers and blogposts where the training of a neural network is defined as learning some underlying probability distribution of the data.
Imagine that you write CNN that outputs whether a coin's image is head or tails.
What is the probability distribution being learn here? Could you give any other concrete example?
Here an example I think.
Imagine a dice that the output depends on the input, so P(2|1) is different from P(3|1).
So the network is trained to learn P(X|Y) but in this case we can easily see that there is an underlying probability distribution for each input value, and the model will be learning those, because we borrow the samples from that distribution.
So one can imagine each number of the dice having an associated probability distribution, in the real world.
But I can not imagine a specific image of a cat mapping to a probability of cat or dog.
I do not see this in the images example.

Could you link a few examples of such claims?

Typically, a machine learning (hence also deep learning) classification problem is formalized as follow:
We have a random variable $Y$ which serves as output an which value can correspond to several classes output $C_0, C_1, ..., C_n$. This r.v $Y$ has an underlying probability distribution $P(Y)$. (In your case, can say that in the nature there are 2 times more pictures of cats that dogs i.e $P(Y=dog)=\frac{1}{3}, P(Y=cat)=\frac{2}{3}$).
We have random variables $(X_j)_{j=0}^{n}$ which are predictors, that we think are linked with the output variable through a probability distribution $P(X,Y)$. (In your case, those predictors are all the pixels constituting an image).
By training your CNN model, what you are trying to do is to learn the underlying probability distribution $P(Y|X)$ (i.e What are chances an image is a cat/dog knowing its pixels look like X). You can see that you easily get this probability by using Bayes theorem $P(Y|X)=\frac{P(X,Y)}{P(X)}=\frac{P(X|Y)*P(Y)}{P(X)}$. Here you can consider $P(X|Y)$ as the probability distribution of your dataset (CNN learned that this pixel set $(X_i)_0^j$ belongs to this class $Y_i$).
Note that the probability distribution ($P(X)$ of your samples does not change in the learning process since it represent fundamental characteristics of your population (e.g There are always black pixel at the corners of images and white pixels at the center mindless of if the picture is a dog or cat one)
As a conclusion, your CNN tries to approximate as best the conditional probability $P(Y|X)$ with the dataset you provide to it.

Nice first answer! I find it a huge help to think of all regression and classification problems (at least discriminative models) in terms of Bayes’ theorem as you do here.

Thank you Dave! It really helped me too, grasping further concepts like covariate or concept shift.

Do we know P(X)/P(Y) ?

In practice you know P(Y). You can estimate P(X) with your data, but you don't want to do this often.
